# How to add instant zoom in and out effect to a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, zoom

I have MP4 that i want to zoom in then zoom out then repeat/loop till the end of video, every zoom in and out is 3sec long between them, zoom in must be instant left and then zoom out and again instant right then back out to normal scale. I have the codes below but I couldn't get the results that I want.
If you help me, I will be grateful. 
Thanks in advance...
ffmpeg -i "hr.mp4" -filter_complex [0:v]scale=854:480,zoompan=z='if(lt(mod(t\,120)\,60)\'" out.mp4

and this code

ffmpeg -i "hr.mp4" "filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih,zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,3),3),zoom+1.8000,zoom-0.0865)':d=1:x='320-(320/zoom)':y='240-(240/zoom)'" out.mp4

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23651

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help @Gyan. But I have a small problem. Zoom effect is working with this code but not zoom out.                                                                         
 ffmpeg -i HR.avi -vf scale=iw*10:ih*10,zoompan=d=300:z='min(pzoom+0.0015,1.5),zoom-0.04*st(1,1),zoom+0.04+0*st(1,0))' o.mp4 I want to use zoom like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS9xh5NDRuM